# flexbox overflow on mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, safari

Ok. I'm trying to get a simple little sliding panel of images.

I have a working version. My problem is browser compatibility.

It works fine on chrome desktop. But on mobile and safari desktop, the images lose their aspect ratio and they try to squeeze in with each other.

The HTML is pretty basic

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  ...
</div>
```

Same with the CSS/SCSS

```css
.slideshow {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  img {
    margin-right: 1em;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

## [Live Example](http://codepen.io/cruznunez/pen/rLvpZN)

Try viewing that post in chrome desktop and safari desktop.

Chrome should have everything working smoothly.

Safari should show all the images squished together.

Any solutions? Or perhaps another way to produce the same result as on the chrome browser but works on all/most platforms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same effect achieved if you use this CSS

```css
.slideshow {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  img {
    height: calc(100% - 4px);
  }
}
```

`calc(100% - 4px)` to avoid y-scrollbar

## [Live Example](http://codepen.io/cruznunez/pen/JKvrJJ)

Yes. I answered my own question. Deal with it.